# How can we display an event with recordtype preselected in lightning page tab component?

Tags: lightning

I want to have a component which allows creating a new event with a recordtype preselected in lightning page Tab component.

I think we can create an action with preselected recordtype, but i want the event as a tab within a lightning page.

Is this possible by point and click or should it be a custom component?
[image]

Comment: This feels like something you can try to answer on your own. Create an action and see how it behaves, if it doesn't behave the way you want, try different declarative options. If the declarative options don't work, you have your answer. My instinct however, is that you will need a visual flow or component.

Comment: I too feel it requires a custom component. I know actions work but I don't think we have it in a tab.at least couldnt find anything documented. Just wanted to see if anyone else has a way to do it before i start dev on the component